# animated PNG Support

Tags: images, png, animated

I know PNGs are pretty much supported across most browsers if not all at this point.

Are Animated PNG or APNG supported if PNG is supported or are they separate?

Do e-mail programs have the same support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was about to post PNG are cannot be animated but then a quick search ... argh!

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG) mentions an [extension for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehkepjiconegkhpodgoaeamnpckdbblp), and has a link to this [test - your -  APNG - support](http://philip.html5.org/tests/apng/tests.html) page

The page seems to kind of work in Firefox and Opera, but it's not very informative and seems in a sort of experimental state still. Then animations are not the most exciting I have seen either, we have pretty cool animated .gif lying around the web after all these years of practicing with a limited format.  This png, I hope the animation is just a bad example because I was expecting more.

It doesn't work in standard Chrome, Safari or IE either.

Anyhow, it seems we have yet to see throbbing/pulsating .png laden web pages yet.

So I figure it may be a  while  until any mail clients support APNG. Unless Google jumps in, you know how they always surprise us with all the cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, only Firefox (at least v8) supports APNG.  One method you may like to implement is to use the Javascript method demonstrated here:

http://ajaxian.com/archives/detect-if-the-browser-supports-apng