# What alternatives to Animated GIFs are natively supported on all popular modern browsers on tablets, etc. without pluggins?

Tags: animated

I was looking for an alternative animated images to Animated GIFS.

But per [CanIUseit](http://caniuse.com/#search=apng) support for APNGs  seems to being phased *out*.  And [MNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mng) support isn't even listed there and pages about it don't even mention Chrome (suggesting those pages are very very old)

*Clarification*: This is for a **web app**, so it'll need to support:
 - Safari on iPad (so can't depend on extensions)
 - Chrome on Windows and Mac
 - Safari 6.0+ on Mac
 - Chrome on Android

Comment: For APNG support, see also the question: [animated PNG Support](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/22802/17633)

Comment: @unor, that answer assumes pluggins. See my update above (can't use pluggins)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 / CSS3 Animations is supported by all Modern Browsers and is far superior than the likes of GIF in many ways by allowing user input and the benefits of being rich in color compared to that of animated gifs that generally look rubbish and are limited in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5/CSS3 animations work in the latest browsers, but not in IE previous to v10. Many people still use IE8 & 9, which should be taken into account - at least make sure they see a static backup image if the animation isn't necessary. Flash works excellent for animations and most users have the Flash plugin; however, a static backup image should be in place for those who do not. And, depending on how complicated the animation is, jQuery could be useful.